xUnit VSTest Adapter not discovering tests
I am running xunit tests (.net framework 4.8) on Azure devops using the VSTest task, but the adapter is not discovering any tests. Running the same version of vstest.console.exe locally runs fine.
This is the output from the local run:
Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 17.9.0 (x64)
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Starting test execution, please wait...
A total of 1 test files matched the specified pattern.
[xUnit.net 00:00:00.00] xUnit.net VSTest Adapter v2.5.7+8f2703126a (64-bit .NET Framework 4.8.4645.0)
[xUnit.net 00:00:02.96]   Discovering: <assembly>.UnitTests
[xUnit.net 00:00:03.34]   Discovered:   <assembly>.UnitTests
[xUnit.net 00:00:03.34]   Starting:     <assembly>.UnitTests
<test output>
[xUnit.net 00:00:17.86]   Finished:     <assembly>.UnitTests
Total tests: 942
     Passed: 924
     Failed: 18
 Total time: 18.2128 Seconds

And this is the output from the devops run:
Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 17.9.0 (x64)
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
vstest.console.exe "..."
/Settings:"C:\a\_temp\t2c4p5qgmxl.tmp.runsettings"
/Logger:"trx"
/TestAdapterPath:"C:\a\1\s"
Starting test execution, please wait...
A total of 1 test files matched the specified pattern.
[xUnit.net 00:00:00.00] xUnit.net VSTest Adapter v2.5.7+8f2703126a (64-bit .NET Framework 4.8.4614.0)
[xUnit.net 00:00:00.39]   Discovering:  <assembly>.UnitTests
[xUnit.net 00:00:00.79]   Discovered:   <assembly>.UnitTests
[xUnit.net 00:00:00.80]   Starting:     <assembly>.UnitTests
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.43]   Finished:     <assembly>.UnitTests
No test is available in C:\a\1\s\<test assembly>. Make sure that test discoverer & executors are registered and platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again.

Has anyone run across this before? or is there any additional diagnostics that are available?
I've tried running locally as well as comparing assembly version adding / removing various assemblies.
This is the current list of packages:
<packages>
  <package id="AutoMapper" version="3.3.1" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Castle.Core" version="5.1.1" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="FluentAssertions" version="6.10.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="MassTransit" version="8.0.16" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="MassTransit.Abstractions" version="8.0.16" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces" version="7.0.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Microsoft.CodeCoverage" version="17.9.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions" version="7.0.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" version="7.0.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" version="7.0.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Diagnostics.HealthChecks" version="6.0.1" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Diagnostics.HealthChecks.Abstractions" version="6.0.1" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Abstractions" version="7.0.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions" version="7.0.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions" version="6.0.1" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Options" version="6.0.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives" version="7.0.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" version="17.9.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Microsoft.TestPlatform.ObjectModel" version="17.8.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="MongoDB.Bson" version="2.14.1" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Moq" version="4.18.4" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="NuGet.Frameworks" version="6.5.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Buffers" version="4.5.1" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Collections.Immutable" version="1.5.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.ComponentModel.Annotations" version="4.7.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource" version="6.0.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Memory" version="4.5.5" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Numerics.Vectors" version="4.5.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Reflection.Metadata" version="1.6.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" version="6.0.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Text.Encodings.Web" version="6.0.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Text.Json" version="6.0.7" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Threading.Channels" version="6.0.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions" version="4.5.4" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.ValueTuple" version="4.5.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="xunit" version="2.7.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="xunit.abstractions" version="2.0.3" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="xunit.assert" version="2.7.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="xunit.core" version="2.7.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="xunit.extensibility.core" version="2.7.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="xunit.extensibility.execution" version="2.7.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="xunit.analyzers" version="1.11.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="xunit.runner.visualstudio" version="2.5.7" targetFramework="net48" developmentDependency="true" />
</packages>


Could you please post the pipeline or the unit test task code?

Have you built your solution before the VSTest step? Could you please share your VSTest definition? It seemed that you configured the VSTest task to search for test assemblies under the path $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\<test assembly>. Please check in the logs of build step if the assemblies were generated in this path.
